# C++ error: conflicting return type specified for... templated sub-class

Tags: c++, templates

Upon first glance, everything seems to be correct, but this code will NOT compile. However, if I were to change the return type of the base class to be `double *` then it will compile. Can someone explain how/why the compiler does not see the template type "T" as a valid return type.

**Base class:**

```
01 template <typename T>
02 class DefaultValueFunctorBase {
03   public:
04     virtual const T operator() (void) const = 0;
05 };
```

**Sub-class:**

```
01 class DblPtrDft : public DefaultValueFunctorBase<double *> {
02   public:
03     DblPtrDft (double default_value_)
04     : DefaultValueFunctorBase<double *>(),
05       _default_value(default_value_),
06       _default_value_ptr(&_default_value)
07     {}
08 
09     const double * operator() (void) const { return _default_value_ptr; }
10 
11   private:
12     const double *_default_value_ptr;
13     const double _default_value;
14 };
```

**ERROR:**

> DblPtrDft.h:09: error: conflicting return type specified for ‘virtual
>   const double* DblPtrDft::operator()() const’
>   DefaultValueFunctorBase.h:04: error:   overriding ‘const T
>   DefaultValueFunctorBase::operator()() const [with T = double*]’

Comment: double* const is not the same as double const*

Comment: @AndyProwl Can you please make an answer and demonstrate what the proper code should look like?

Comment: Will do so, give me a moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `const T` should be read as `T const`, which makes it clear that the `const` qualifier applies to `T`. Thus, when you replace `T` with `double*` in your template instantiation, what you get as the return type of the base class's call operator is `double* const`.

This is different from the return type you have in the derived class's call operator (i.e. `const double*`, which is equivalent to `double const*`). In the superclass, you return a constant pointer to a `double`. On the subclass, you return a non-constant pointer to a constant `double`.

One way to fix your application is this:

```
template<typename T>
class DefaultValueFunctorBase
{
    public:
        // Do not return T const here: the top-level const is useless anyway
        virtual T operator() (void) const = 0;
};

// Instantiate your base class template with double const* rather than double*
class DblPtrDft : public DefaultValueFunctorBase<double const*>
{
public:
    DblPtrDft (double default_value_)
    : DefaultValueFunctorBase<double const*>(), // Same change here of course...
    _default_value(default_value_),
    _default_value_ptr(&_default_value)
    {}

    // Return a double const*, consistently with the instantiated template...
    double const* operator() (void) const { return _default_value_ptr; }

private:
    double const*_default_value_ptr;
    double const _default_value;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your overridden function returns a `const double *`, but the virtual function, with `T = double *`, actually has a return type of `double * const`.

Comment: Can you please demonstrate what the proper code should look like?